# Create a Google Analytics segment for users that visit my site every month and every other month

Tags: google-analytics, advanced-segments

I'm trying to determine page popularity for users that visit regularly.

I want the Behavior > All Pages report, but only for users that have visited the site at least once each month.

I'm unclear if I can accomplish this using "Days Since Last Session" as a condition for a segment.

I'm also interested in the same information for users that visit every other month and quarterly.

Comment: There probably aren't many users that regularly visit any website regularly, but only every other month.

Comment: I should have referred to it as a web application in my question.  There are many functions that could draw users back at regular intervals, like checking account balances.